# How to detect if action filter is executing due to controller scope or action method scope?

Tags: asp.net-mvc

I would like to immediately return from an action filter when it is executing as a result of attachment to a controller if the action filter has also been specified on the action method.  The goal is to allow me to override the controller action filter at the action method level when necessary.

I could do this if I created 2 separate action filters and have the controller specific version check for the action method one prior to execution.  I'd rather avoid the creation of 2 types if possible.

Comment: Can you show us your filter code and how yous use it actually with your controller/action?

Comment: It's just an action filter with OnActionExecuting override, I don't think the actual implementation is important, more so the concept.  At the heart of the problem an action filter can detect if its on a controller or action but I can't detect if its currently executing in one of those contexts or not.

Comment: I search for the existence of the attribute using the ActionExecutingContext.ActionDescriptor and ActionExecutingContext.ActionDescriptor.ControllerDescriptor properties along with GetCustomAttributes() method.

Comment: Have you put `AllowMultiple = true` on your custom attribute?

Comment: Because if you set that property to false for custom attribute, the action filter will be executed once even if the controller has been decorated with the same attribute.

Answer (score 2):

For ASP.NET Core 1.1

```
var currentFilter = filterContext.ActionDescriptor
                                 .FilterDescriptors
                                 .Select(filterDescriptor => filterDescriptor)
                                 .FirstOrDefault(filterDescriptor => ReferenceEquals(filterDescriptor.Filter, this));
if (currentFilter == null)
{
    return;
}


if (currentFilter.Scope == FilterScope.Action)
{
    //...
}
if (currentFilter.Scope == FilterScope.Controller)
{
    //...
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You may access `Filter` object from action attribute and then check the scope:

```
[ControllerScope]
public class HomeController : Controller
{
    [ControllerScope]
    public ActionResult Index()
    {
        return View();
    }
}

public class ActionScopeAttribute : ActionFilterAttribute
{
}

public class ControllerScopeAttribute : ActionFilterAttribute
{
    public override void OnActionExecuting(ActionExecutingContext filterContext)
    {
        var filters = FilterProviders.Providers.GetFilters(filterContext.Controller.ControllerContext,
            filterContext.ActionDescriptor)
            .ToList();

        var filter = filters.First(f => f.Instance is ControllerScopeAttribute);

        if (filter.Scope == FilterScope.Action)
        {
            //your logic
        }
        if (filter.Scope == FilterScope.Controller)
        {
            //your logic
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks Ilya but as I mentioned above I wanted to avoid creating separate types.

Comment: @JeremyF, ok it is possible to find filter and then check the scope. I've added the code to answer.

Comment: Sorry but I don't want to return in *all* cases but instead only stop execution for the instance thats defined in controller scope.  The reason is that there are property values set for each instance and they would be different.  The values specific to the action method override are the ones to be used in the action filter.

Comment: @JeremyF, it is just an example of `FilterScope.Action` and `FilterScope.Controller` and it isn't mandatory to return. It means you got `filter.Scope` and can write your own logic. I've corrected the answer code.

Comment: Ilya you had to create 2 types so that you could check for the existence of the action method specific type from the controller specific type so you could abort the controller behavior.  This is what I was trying to avoid entirely.

Comment: @JeremyF, one type can be used. If you assign `ControllerScope` attribute to both action and controller it will be called one time and `filter.Scope` will be `FilterScope.Action`. If assign to controller only - scope will be `FilterScope.Controller`.

Comment: You are always getting the first attribute, how do you know if its the one that is currently executing and is attached to the controller?  I don't know if I'm missing something in your explanation.  My concern is that when you find the filters that are attached you have no idea if they represent the current filter that is executing so that you can make some decision if you should return or continue processing.

Comment: Well, if you add the same attribute both to controller AND action, how many times this filter will be executed? My test shows it is executed only once. So if you found this filter - you found the `currently executing` filter, I guess.